# Merge objects that are inside an Array inside one unique object

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, reduce, google-datalayer

I have an issue here. I have an array with properties:

```
let products = [
  { 
    nome_evento: 'Show1',
    preco: 100,
    quantidade: 1
  },
  { 
    nome_evento: 'Show2',
    preco: 200,
    quantidade: 3
  }, 
  { 
    nome_evento: 'Show3',
    preco: 300,
    quantidade: 5
  }
]
```

Actually is an array of the Google dataLayer. I need to get all the properties inside of all the objects that are inside this array, and put them all inside a unique object, to look like this:

```
const finalObj = {
{ 
    nome_evento: 'Show1',
    preco: 100,
    quantidade: 1
  },
  { 
    nome_evento: 'Show2',
    preco: 200,
    quantidade: 3
  }, 
  { 
    nome_evento: 'Show3',
    preco: 300,
    quantidade: 5
  }
}
```

This is what I tried to do, but it keeps giving me the last object inside the array, and I need them all:

```
let productData = []
  products.forEach(product => {
   let item = {}
   item['nome_evento'] = product.nome_evento
   item['preco'] = product.preco
   item['quantidade'] = product.quantidade
   productData.push(item)
  })

const finalObj = productData.reduce(function(acc, x) {
    for (var key in x) acc[key] = x[key];
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(finalObj)
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: You won't be able to create an object like `finalObj` because the "child object" don't have a key. Each child object needs to be assigned to a key (ie "Show1", "Show2", etc)

Comment: each property in an object must have a name, the object format you want is not valid

Comment: Your `const finalObj = {...}` is not a appropriate JS code. You can't do `{ {key: value } }`.

Comment: `finalObj` is impossible to accomplish. Object entries must have keys. It just kind of looks like you replaced the array brackets with object curly braces...

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, the result you're asking for is not valid javascript and is hence not achievable. Maybe what you need is each `nome_evento` as a key in a new object? So you can look up your stuff like `result['Show1'].preco === 100`.

```js
const data = [  {     nome_evento: 'Show1',    preco: 100,    quantidade: 1  },  {     nome_evento: 'Show2',    preco: 200,    quantidade: 3  },   {     nome_evento: 'Show3',    preco: 300,    quantidade: 5  }]

const result = data
  .reduce((acc, { nome_evento, ...rest }) => ({
    ...acc,
    [nome_evento]: rest
  }), {})
  
 console.log(result)
```